# CCM* test in contiki

Tags: c, encryption, contiki

With no changes to any of the other files, I am trying to run [ccm-star-tests](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/llsec/ccm-star-tests) on z1 motes in cooja simulator.

For [encryption](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/llsec/ccm-star-tests/encryption/tests.c) the mote output is:

```
Testing verification ... Failure
Testing encryption ... Failure
Testing decryption ... Success
```

For [verification](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/llsec/ccm-star-tests/verification/tests.c) the mote output is:

```
Testing AES-128 ... Failure
Testing verification ... Failure
```

From [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/33268447/) I followed,

> add these lines to your project-conf.h:
>
> #undef AES_128_CONF
>
> #define AES_128_CONF cc2420_aes_128_driver
>
> and this to your C-file:
>
> #include "lib/aes-128.h"

But no success. What am I missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow seems like the wrong place for a bug report. Since you posted this already to the [correct place on GitHub](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2197), I would suggest that you delete this question.

Comment: Reason to post this here too is I am not sure whether it is bug or I am mistaken. And I am falling short of time. The response on this community is much faster which I need. People have used the code earlier and I am not able to do this means there is a chance that I am missing something. So please let me have this question here. Moreover the answer to this question might help in future too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Cooja uses the `msp430` microcontroller emulator called `mspsim` to emulate the operations of the CC2420 radio, and the emulated CC2420 chip in `mspsim` does not have support for AES hardware acceleration.

These lines say "use the cc2420 hardware:

```
#undef AES_128_CONF
#define AES_128_CONF cc2420_aes_128_driver
```

Either remove them or change to:

```
#define AES_128_CONF   aes_128_driver
```

That will use the software-only AES implementation and should work. It will be *very* slow though, compared to the HW-enabled version.

Comment: Can you give me hint on how I can use AES hardware acceleration then?

Comment: Also I don't understand why it doesn't work if I remove `#define AES_128_CONF   aes_128_driver`.

Comment: Here https://www.comsys.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/papers/2013/2013-hummen-6lowpan.pdf in 4.1.4 they have used hardware acceleration support for sky motes.